# Relating Chromatic Numbers of a Critical Graph to Edge-Connectedness

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove the statement that any critical $k$-chromatic graph is
$(k-1)$-edge-connected. Let us consider a graph $G$ such that $\chi(G) = k$ and
$G$ is critical. Hence, for any $v \in G, \chi(G \setminus \{v\}) = k-1.$ Given
this, I hypothesize that this implies that $v$ is connected to $k-1$ other
vertices in $G$ such that those $k-1$ vertices form an induced subgraph
of $K_{k-1}$ in $G$. However, given this particular situation, it is difficult
for me to imply that the removal of fewer than $k-1$ edges in this graph will
allow $G$ to remain connected. I can see how this may hold for removing
specifically $v$'s edges that are adjacent to the given $K_{k-1}$, but this is
a very particular set of edges within the graph. Any suggestions on how to
move forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is currently a hint. If you can't figure it out, I will add more details.

Assume $G$ has an edge-cut $[X,Y]$ of less than $k-1$ edges.
Both $X$ and $Y$ are $k-1$-colorable, since $G$ is critical.
Take any proper $k-1$-coloring of $X$ and $Y$

Now consider the bipartite graph $H$ whose parts are $A$ and $B$, where the
vertices of $A$ are the color classes of $X$ and the vertices of $B$ are the color classes of $Y$. For $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ add edge $ab$ if and only if $G$
has *NO* edge between the color class $a$ and the color class $b$.

Now show that $H$ has a perfect matching and conclude the result from this.